# How does one open the HUD from the command line.

Tags: bash, hud

<kbd>Alt</kbd> is used to open the HUD in 12.04.

I'd like to use <kbd>alt</kbd> to execute a *second* action as well as open the HUD by having <kbd>alt</kbd> execute an executable script.

So <kbd>Alt</kbd> = script, that does HUD and other stuff.

I know how to do all of this except call the HUD from the command line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The HUD service is available as a service on DBus, so if you'd just like to poll it for information you can do that with a gdbus command, like this.

```
gdbus call --session --dest com.canonical.hud --object-path /com/canonical/hud --method com.canonical.hud.StartQuery "my query" 5
```

If you're trying to get Unity to show the HUD prompt you can do that with the XTest extension using [xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) like this:

```
xdotool key alt
```

If you're interested in playing with HUD it's probably best to use the `hud-gtk` tool which is in the [indicator-appmenu-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/indicator-appmenu-tools) package.

Comment: What does the `5` at the end of your code do?

Comment: The 5 adjusts the number of entries that are returned.  So if you had some way to display more entries, you could pass a larger number.

Comment: I copied the command into the terminal and I got the following output: `('', @a(sssssv) [], <'query key'>)` Am I missing part of the command, or does part of the command need to be modified in order to work correctly?

Comment: change the "my query" bit to something that might be in your current hud - perhaps "file"

Comment: Is there official documentation for the HUD DBUS interface? Searching doesn't seem to turn up much.

Comment: I'm also looking for the documentation as requested in the above comment. Executing a search works, but it's not clear where to go from there. I see an ExecuteQuery function on the D-Bus interface, but the arguments are not clear to me...

Comment: In HUD 2.0 we added a library libhud-client that provides a way to access the HUD service with an API.  It's not currently in raring, but should show up in S.  I wouldn't recommend using the DBus interface, but instead using the library.

Answer (score 4):

You can query the hud from the command line using `hud-cli`, but it doesn't actually raise the Unity side of hud and it doesn't let you activate the results.  It's really only useful for testing hud searches.

I don't think there is a way to do what you are describing at this time.

Comment: You're my hero. And I might be a noob at Python, but my limited abilities have solved many of these little challenges in the past. I'll try to re-write my own HUD GUI.

Comment: This is sooo cool!!! Can I do the same with the dashboard search!?!??!?