# HUD in other window managers (especially xmonad)

Tags: software-recommendation, window-manager, desktop-environments, hud, xmonad

It seems that [HUD (Heads Up Display)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/HUD) is tightly tied to `Unity`. However I just use [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) as a window manager, especially I don't use `unity`.

Is there a way to use HUD within `xmonad` (or more generally withing other window managers and desktop environments)? If so, what are the detailed steps to do it with minimal dependencies on `unity`?

Are there alternative projects which similar functionality like HUD which work together with many window managers without too much pain?

Comment: The thing that makes HUD work is that Unity already has all the menus centrally. For any other WM, you would need a way to inform it about menus, which is not really a job of the VM.

Comment: Really would like this too.  Please share if you find a solution.

Comment: Yeah, I will post it if I find something. I really want to have it. But at the moment I don't have the time to think about it :-(

Comment: interesting... I thought the environment read and parsed the menus on the fly. since Ubuntu is open source, couldn't another window manager adopt Ubuntu's menu repository?

Comment: Would this be of use: http://askubuntu.com/a/515365/421237? Dmenu should be usable with xmonad and other window managers.

Comment: Doesn't a HUD require composition? All the window managers mentioned are tiling, they are not capable of a HUD.

Comment: @crimsonspectre I am using dmenu already but I cannot acces menus of applications like gimp or libreoffice via dmenu, but HUD can do this. The ability to access menus of applications via keyboard in a unified way is the killer feature why I want something like HUD for xmonad.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your **Desktop Environment** i.e. Unity, is a *plugin of* the Window Manager **Compiz**. 
Similarly GNOME 3 is a plugin of Mutter.

So thing is that, the menus of your *Window Manager* are tightly coupled to the Dash of the *Desktop Environment*, which can be only done via a plugin.

If there were a Unity plugin for Mutter or Kwin or other Window managers, then they could be used too instead of Compiz