# Unity HUD on other DEs

Tags: desktop-environments, hud

I'm trying to choose a desktop environment for my future laptop, and have this thing with Unity: I generally don't like it so much (lacking configurability, high resources, etc.), but while I was using Ubuntu I found the HUD brilliant.

Is there

1. Any way to get that HUD in other DEs / with other WMs, or
2. Anything like the HUD in Unity, to search application menus with a keybinding?

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/138657/is-there-a-shell-independent-hud-like-menu-search-tool-for-xfce-gnome-cinnamon?lq=1

Comment: @JorgeCastro Hehewoops :) Don't know how I missed that . . .