# unity-like HUD on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: unity, gnome, 18.04, hud

### Question

I would like to know what are the possible ways of using an unity-like **HUD** (Heads Up Display) on Ubuntu 18.04, preferably with the gnome shell as default.

by **HUD** I mean the access and search of **menu items** (not applications or files!) when pressing (and releasing)  <kbd>alt</kbd>.

Are there usable gnome extension or third-party apps that works in 18.04?

### Discussion

There are already some discussion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138657/is-there-a-shell-independent-hud-like-menu-search-tool-for-xfce-gnome-cinnamon). But this is less specific, as I am searching for an Ubuntu 18.04 (with Gnome shell) solution.

some of the solutions indicated are:

- [plotinus](https://github.com/p-e-w/plotinus) seems promising, but only works with GTK+ apps.
- [Gnome Global Application Menu(HUD for Gnome)](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1250/gnome-global-application-menu/), comments say it doesn't work in 18.04, although the last comment (from 06.05.18) says the latest version if installed manually from github should work in 18.04. (I would appreciate a detailed instruction of how to install an extension manually)

Comment: You still can install Unity with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-unity-desktop`.

Comment: I have not problem to help you. Create a github account if you have not one. Open an issue here: https://github.com/lestcape/Gnome-Global-AppMenu/issues/new See also a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJRFeiJIDVo

Comment: thanks lestcape. It is actually not as hard as I first imagined and your instructions (on github) were enough.  The extensions seems very promising. 
It did work with some programs I just tried, but it seemed to slow down the computer a bit.  If I have a concrete issue, I'll definitely open it on github.

Comment: Marcelo, yes  it not SEEMED to slow down the computer. It slow down the computer a lot. It's a fact. https://github.com/lestcape/Gnome-Global-AppMenu/issues/59

Answer (score 2):

An Unity like HUD menu for the GNOME Desktop Environment using rofi menu

https://github.com/hardpixel/gnome-hud