# How do I enable the powerful menu navigation by keyboard from Unity (16.04) in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome

Maybe people didn't like Unity, but it had a great feature where you tap the Alt key to bring up a menu navigation prompt with partial search of the *current* application's menu entries. This was super useful for Gimp which have a ton of menus, and you didn't require the mouse

**How can I get this back in the new Gnome environment for 18.04?**

Example, you can tap Alt, then type "Layer" and hit enter and you get the "Layers..." dialogue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a shell-independent HUD-like menu search tool for Xfce/GNOME/Cinnamon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138657/is-there-a-shell-independent-hud-like-menu-search-tool-for-xfce-gnome-cinnamon) I don't think the HUD is available outside of Unity and Ubuntu Mate.

Comment: Just a pointer, you can still install and use Unity: https://askubuntu.com/q/1040890/480481